# How to add a custom button in a registered model in django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on how to put a button next to the delete button [image: here]? I want to put a confirm and deny button next to it, that when I click it, it will send an email to the user that his/her application is accepted or denied. I've searched online for a solution and also read some similar questions here, but I am not sure whether or not those are right things to go to.

Comment: you can easily add Accepted/Denied button in list_page. Why you want this feature in  add/change page?

Comment: @shahbazahmad Thank you for your response! I want to add those buttons there to let a tutor know that their application is accepted or not. My plan is to create a signal so that when I click on accepted or denied, an email will be sent to that tutor saying that there application is accepted or denied. Do you have any suggestion on how can I implement this plan of mine better? I would really appreciate it if you could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make buttons for confirm and deny in list_page by writing **confirmed()** and **denied()** method , then you append your custom urls in admin urls by overriding **get_urls()** method and mapped those url to a view method **confirmed_application()** and **denied_application()**.

After processing your logic then you can redirect same change_list page.

```
@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['your_model_fields', 'confirmed', 'denied']


    def confirmed(self, obj):
        url = reverse('admin:confirm_url', kwargs={'id': obj.id})
        return format_html('<a class="button" href="{}">Confirm</a>', url)

    def denied(self, obj):
        url = reverse('admin:denied_url', kwargs={'id': obj.id})
        return format_html('<a class="button" href="{}">Deny</a>', url)


    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path('confirm/<int:id>', self.confirmed_application, name='confirm_url'),
            path('deny/<int:id>', self.denied_application, name='denied_url'),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls


    def confirmed_application(self, request, id):
        # you get object_id you can do whatever you want
        # you can send a mail

        # after processed all logic you can redirect same modeladmin changelist page
        redirect_url = "admin:{}_{}_changelist".format(self.opts.app_label, self.opts.model_name)
        return redirect(reverse(redirect_url))


    def denied_application(self, request, id):
        # same as  confirmed_application do the logic
        ...
```